# xcresults tool is not able to export screenshots for failure cases ( xcresults-1.17.1 )

Tags: ui-automation, reporting, xctest, allure

@Artem Eroshenko, Thank you for xcresults tool. When I run the run "xcresults export abc.xcresult results", it is generating files with zero bytes as below: 12605a3a-2b1d-4975-aeec-6538b93f941c-attachment.

Ideally this should be 12605a3a-2b1d-4975-aeec-6538b93f941c-attachment.jpeg format. xcresults tool is stripping and changing the format. Hence the screenshots are not visible for failure cases. I would really appreciate if you can provide a solution for this. Thanks a lot in advance.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpYS2.png)

Ideally allure report should be showing screenshot for the error case also. This is not happening with latest xcresults tool with xcode 15.0.1.
Previously it was absolutely good with older xcode versions. ex: xcode 14.2